# Change profile at creating new account with firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to update the profile of a firebase account just after the creation of the account but its not working

I've tried to check if it worked with

```
 console.log(AuthUser.user.displayName());
```

and it says displayName doesn't exist so I think I'm doing something wrong

this is my new user creation code

```
    auth.doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordOne)
    .then(authUser => {
    this.setState(() => ({ ...INITIAL_STATE }));
    authUser.user.updateProfile({
        displayName: firstName + " "+lastName
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
    this.setState(byPropKey('error', error));
    });
```

Comment: where did you print this ```console.log(AuthUser.user.displayName());```? you might be logging the display name before the updateProfile completes. Check firebase, the user profile may have already been updated.

Comment: onAuthStateChange does not catch updateProfile events

Comment: I've check on firebase console and the profile is not being updated (but authUser.user.updateProfile is not throwing any error)

Comment: try to add this. ```user.updateProfile({displayName: 'test-name'}).then(function() {
  var displayName = user.displayName;
console.log('profile updated');
}, function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});```

Comment: It worked! post it and I'll accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 authUser.user.updateProfile({
    displayName: firstName + " "+lastName
  })
```

this works, the problem was that I had to change

```
  console.log(AuthUser.user.displayName());
```

to

```
  console.log(AuthUser.user.displayName);
```